# ASP.net Core - SwaggerResponseExample not outputting specified example

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I' using ASP.net Core and swagger, I have created the following method and verbose documentation:

```cs
/// <summary>Creates a package with the requested information.</summary>
/// <param name="createPackage">The package information to create.</param>
/// <response code="201" cref="PackageCreatedExample">Created</response>
/// <returns><see cref="PackageCreated"/> package created.</returns>
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerResponse(201, "Package created", typeof(PackageCreated))]
[SwaggerResponse(400, "Validation failure", typeof(ApiErrorResult))]
[SwaggerResponseExample(201, typeof(PackageCreatedExample))]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePackage(PackageCreate createPackage)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(new ApiErrorResult(ModelState));
    }

    var createdPackageInfo = new PackageCreated();

    // Created item and location returned.
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetPackage), new { createdPackageInfo.Id, Version = "2" }, createdPackageInfo);
}
```

I am trying to get an example response to appear in swagger but it always defaults the response sample as follows:

[image]

As you can see from the code above, I created a "PackageCreatedExample" class that I want to be picked up and used in swagger but it's just being ignored.  I tried using comments `response code="201" cref="PackageCreatedExample"` and wrote the `SwaggerResponseExample` attribute, but neither get picked up.  Here's my example code:

```cs
public class PackageCreatedExample : IExamplesProvider<PackageCreated>
    {
        public PackageCreated GetExamples()
        {
            return new PackageCreated {
                Outcome = "PackageCreated",
                Reference = "6178",
                ShippingDocumentation = new List<Documentation> {
                    new Documentation {
                        Document = "JVBERi0xLjMNCjEgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvQ2F...",
                        Format = "Pdf",
                        Type = DocumentationType.TYPE3
                    }
                },
                ReturnsDocumentation = new List<Documentation> {
                    new Documentation {
                        Document = "YmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZw0KL1BhZ2VzIDQgMJVBERi0xLjMNCjEgMCBv...",
                        Format = "doc",
                        Type = DocumentationType.TYPE4
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the author, this method should not be used anymore ([link](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters#do-not-use-this-filter-unless-you-have-to)). This [section](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#include-descriptions-from-xml-comments) of the official readme describes the way how the descriptions and examples should be handled.

In short, you have to

1. Remove all the annotations and use the followings instead:

```
/// <summary>Creates a package with the requested information.</summary>
/// <param name="createPackage">The package information to create.</param>
/// <returns>package created.</returns>
/// <response code="201">Created</response>
/// <response code="400">Validation failure</response>
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PackageCreated), 201)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiErrorResult), 400)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePackage(PackageCreate createPackage)
```

2. Enable generating XML documentation under Project -> Properties -> Build tab -> Check `XML documentation file` in the Output section
3. Configure swagger to use the generated XML file

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
      new OpenApiInfo
      {
          Title = "My API - V1",
          Version = "v1"
      }
   );

   var filePath = Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "MyApi.xml");
   c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
}
```

4. Add example comments to the properties of your input model classes:

PackageCreate.cs

```
public PackageCreate 
{
  // Built-in type
  /// <summary>
  /// Outcome value
  /// </summary>
  /// <example>PackageCreated</example>
  public string Outcome { get; set; }

  // Custom class -> comment its properties in Documentation.cs
  public Documentation { get; set; }

  // Array type -> comment the properties in Documentation.cs
  public IList<Documentation> { get; set; }
}
```

Documentation.cs:

```
public Documentation
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Document name
  /// </summary>
  /// <example>YmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZw0KL1BhZ2VzIDQgMJVBERi0xLjMNCjEgMCBv</example>
  public string Document { get; set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// Document format
  /// </summary>
  /// <example>doc</example> 
  public string Format { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works well for system types.  How does this work for likes of arrays and classes?

Comment: I edited my answer by adding examples for your question. See (4).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you loads for your help!

Comment: When you say remove all annotations, you mean the `SwaggerResponse` attributes?

Comment: Good question, I updated my answer once more. See (1) for the details.

Comment: This does not seem to allow for different examples for different HTPP status codes. I'd like to show a different example for 200 vs 400 vs 401. How does one go about doing this now?